# What is the name of this circuit in English?

Tags: analog

I hope that this is the right place to ask this question. English isn't my first language. So here is my question. If you are familiar with analog circuits you know about power amplifier. Here is simple schematic.

[image: schematic]
<sub>(source: [gpstronic.com](http://gpstronic.com/stranici/analogova-shemotehnika_files/image004.gif))</sub>

So there are 2 steps in the power amplifier the first one amplifies the voltage(U) and the second one the current(I). Whats the name of the second step. In my language we call this final step with/without transformer but when I search for this in WWW I don't find anything. I will be very grateful if somebody answer to my question.

Comment: When you refer to it as "final step", I'd be tempted to say "output stage" or "power stage". But I'm not native English either.

Answer (score 1):

I could be way off here but T2 & T3 seem to form a class AB amplifier and together with T4 & T5 you get a "Quasi Class AB". T4 & T5 enhances the power output.

Comment: Or is the question more general?  Maybe just "output stage", or "Follower Stage"?  For example "OTL" output stage is output transformerless output stage.

Comment: Yes the question is more general, I'm not asking only for this schematic, but for all power amplifier. Also I forget to mention there are different types of this type schematics. I mean there is schematic with complementary transistors pair with powerful transistors, with medium-power transistor.

Answer (score 1):

The second stage could generically be called a "voltage follower". It's a little more complicated than what we normally think of, because it handles bipolar signals; i.e., signals that can go both above and below ground.

Answer (score -1):

Quasi complementary... if memory serves